# Light occlusion Godot

Tags: android, godot, shadow, gdscript, godot3

Godot 3.6(Android version, GLES2, GLES3(NOT SUPPORTED BY DEVICE))
Objects doesn't cast shadows, by using lightoccluder2d.

I tried also tried to change project settings as other sources suggested doing so, will help me overcome the problem. But nothing worked at all.

It always shows this in output panel:-
drivers/gles2/rasterizer_storage_gles2.cpp:5830 - Condition "status != 0x8CD5" is true. Returned: RID()

And in the error panel it shows this:-
E 0:00:02.009   canvas_light_shadow_buffer_create: Condition "status != 0x8CD5" is true. Returned: RID()
<C++ Source>  drivers/gles2/rasterizer_storage_gles2.cpp:5830 @ canvas_light_shadow_buffer_create()

And there is no effect of shadow polygon. Light is casted in circular shape, no shadows are visible.

Is there any solution for this or the problem is related to device's components or specifically graphics card?

Comment: And recently I have found that light occluder works in 3d projects but not in 2d projects and in 2d projects the the fps drops(lagging), if the character goes near to light(wall light).